# my flutter code displays shows this error. "A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'."

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, dart-null-safety

I am running my dart code embedded with firebase but it shows the above error. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: whats the variable _UserEmail? is that a string? or a model?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 1):

`.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` return nullable User.

You can make it nullable like like

```dart
final UserCredential credential =
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "", password: "");

final User? user = credential.user;

if (user != null) {
} else {
  //failed
}
```

More about [/understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)